# difference between fill() and update() in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

I want to change value in table using ajax in laravel.
But when i use fill(), returning value is "success", but when i use update(), returning value is fail.
My source code is follow.

```
public function deleteCourse($id){
   $test = Course::find($id)->fill(['is_deleted' => 1])->save();
   $res = ['res' => 'success'];
   return json_encode($res);
}
public function deleteCourse($id){
   $test = Course::find($id)->update(['is_deleted'=>1])->save();
   $res = ['res'=>'success'];
   return json_encode($res);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call `->save()` after `->update()`, since it returns a `boolean` 1 or 0 (success or fail). The record is directly updated in the database, so `->save()` is not required.

`fill()` on the other hand doesn't persist anything to the database until you call `->save()`, so it is required in that instance.

```
public function deleteCourse($id){
  $test = Course::find($id)->fill(['is_deleted' => 1])->save();
  $res = ['res' => 'success'];
  return json_encode($res);
}

// OR

public function deleteCourse($id){
  $test = Course::find($id)->update(['is_deleted'=>1]);
  $res = ['res'=>'success'];
  return json_encode($res);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fill will not save into database until you call `->save` on the object.

Update will change the value in the database immediately.

```
$test = Course::find($id)->update(['is_deleted'=>1]);
```

Comment: You're  right. i want to check right but i can't it.
Its not allow me to check some times at once.

Comment: Your answer is as same as above and above is more clear.
Why don't you check above answer?

Comment: You can only accept 1 answer with the checkmark. You can upvote multiple ones (using the arrows).